# Python and sorted dictionary

Tags: python

The purpose is to display the sorted dictionary after removing one element. I wrote code in two different ways. The code of Part I works, but the code of Part II doesn't work.

Why can't the code of Part II produce the correct result?

Part I:

```
food_dictionary = {}

food1 = input("Enter a food you like: ")
food_dictionary[1]=food1

food2 = input("Enter a food you like: ")
food_dictionary[2]=food2

food3 = input("Enter a food you like: ")
food_dictionary[3]=food3

food4 = input("Enter a food you like: ")
food_dictionary[4]=food4

print(food_dictionary)

dislike=int(input("Which one should be removed: "))

del food_dictionary[dislike]

print(sorted(food_dictionary.values()))
```

Part II:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]

food_list={}

for i in x:
    food = input("Enter the name of a food: ")
    food_list[i]={food}

print(food_list)

print(type(food_list))

ask = int(input("Which one should be removed: "))

del food_list[ask]

print(sorted(food_list.values()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{}` in your for loop

```
food_list[i] = food
```

Adding `{}` around `food` makes it a set and ultimately `food_list` becomes like this :

```
{1: {'food1'}, 2: {'food1'}, 3: {'food1'}, 4: {'food1'}}
```

where as you need the values of `food_list` dictionary to be only string.